# How can I get the first or last n rows from a table?

Tags: database, nosql, griddb

I need a function which takes in an integer *n as input, and checks through a database table to return all the rows from the first to the nth row. The function should also be able to return the last n rows from the table.
In the table below, I have 10 rows on the table. If I want to get just the 'head' of the table, or the first 5 rows, I just have to pass 5 to the function and it should return the output I want.
This is similar to the `df.head()` method used in Pandas. The function should not take values equal to or higher than the total number of rows for the table.
I am using GridDB python client and I have created my Factory instance and stored my database table.

```py
'''
-- | id | first_name | last_name  | salary_$  |
-- |----|------------|------------|-----------|
-- | 1  | Josh       | Mac        | 175000    |
-- | 2  | Hong       | Williams   | 150000    |
-- | 3  | Ajay       | Kumar      | 125000    |
-- | 4  | Jay        | Mac        | 100000    |
-- | 5  | John       | Jonah      | 95000     |
-- | 6  | Lucy       | Judas      | 80000     |
-- | 7  | Matthew    | Stones     | 80000     |
-- | 8  | Kang       | Choi       | 70000     |
-- | 9  | Rajiv      | Kumar      | 50000     |
-- | 10 | Smith      | Peters     | 50000     |
'''
```